# Optical Path Length

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction, geometric-optics

Recently I have been studying Waves and Optics and I am stuck trying to understand what the optical path is and how it is derived. Specifically, my notes tell me that the optical path difference is

$$n_1(AB+BC) - n_2(AD),$$

where $n_1$ and $n_2$ are the refractive indices in each medium. What I don't understand is  that why this subtraction isn't zero. In general:

$$c_{medium} = \frac{c_{vacuum}}{n_{medium}}.$$

In my example,

$$c_1 = \frac{(AB+BC)}{t} = \frac{c_2}{n_1},$$

which gives

$$n_1(AB+BC)=c_2t.$$

Similarly, I get

$$n_2(AD)=c_2t.$$

Since t is the same for both, why isn't the subtraction zero here?

[image]

Comment: Why should the traveled time be the same for both routes?

Comment: The moment wave 1 ( the one that travelled AB+BC) is at C , wave 2 is at D so the way I see it is that the amount of time taken to travel AB+BC is the same as the amount of time taken to travel AD , the speeds are different thats why the lengths are different but when you multiply them by n , the way I see it , you should get the same answer always , no matter . I suppose im wrong but cant see how and why .

Comment: Change n, now the time the light travels via ABC has changed but the time for AD has not. So -in general- it can not be the same travel time. Most of the time, the light in the medium is slower and in addition has a longer path, so it clearly takes more time.

Comment: Just adding to @Densch conment: $CD$ is defined as  points on the ***same wavefront***, not exhibiting the same time. Wavefront being perpendicular to rays.

Comment: Ohhhh , I can see my mistake now , thanks both of you !

Comment: The points of a *phase front* travel together -  they are of the same phase, by definition. A *ray* is the orthogonal trajectory of the *phase front*.